# Getting "An error occurred while converting the nvarchar value to JDBC data type DOUBLE."

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to run the method getAllCoupons() which reads the coupons table and sends it back to an angular service, but i get this message
An error occurred while converting the nvarchar value to JDBC data type DOUBLE.
I dont see any field that is wrong.

I initally thought that the date is the problem so i made it a comment, but i still get a problem

My DBDAO code:

```
public ArrayList<Coupon> getAllCoupon() throws CouponException {
        ArrayList<Coupon> coupons = new ArrayList<>();
        Connection con = pool.getConnection();


        try {
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select * from coupons");

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                long id = rs.getLong(1);
                String title = rs.getString(2);
                String message = rs.getString(3);
                String image = rs.getString(4);
            //  Date startDate = rs.getDate(5);
            //  Date endDate = rs.getDate(6);
                int amount = rs.getInt(5);
                double price = rs.getDouble(6);
                Coupontypes type = Coupontypes.valueOf(rs.getString(7));
                coupons.add(new Coupon(id, title, message, image, amount, price, type));

            }

            return coupons;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new CouponException(e.getMessage());

        } finally {
            pool.returnConnection(con);
        }
        }
```

My table:

CouponID    bigint
Title   nvarchar(50)
StartDate   date
EndDate date
Amount  int 
Type    nvarchar(50)
Message nvarchar(MAX)
Price   float   Unchecked
Image   nvarchar(50)

I expect to get a coupon object back so i can display it on an angular website with *ngFor

Comment: Well, the message is pretty clear. You're trying to read a double value from an nvarchar column. Stop using `select *`. Select the columns you actually need, in a well-known order, so that you can know that the column at index 6 is actually the price column and not another one.

Comment: Indeed, field #6 is `Message`, which is `nvarchar`.

Comment: Now i got it, didn't realize that it worked that way.
much appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your trying `java.lang.String` to cast to `java.lang.Double`. If you are storing double as a String, then you can do `double price = new Double(rs.getString(6))`. Make sure your column won't be null and it will always return double value to avoid exception.

Comment: That seems to have solved the problem with the double, but when i try that with date it gives an error " The constructor Date(Date) is undefined)

Comment: use ```rs.getDate(int)``` for date type columns.